# Add to MS word font list a font in resource

Tags: c#, fonts, ms-word

I want to use an add-in to add a font to the font list in word without having to install the font.

I can use th AddFontFile method to add the font to my privateFontCollection object (and it works),but I want to load the font from the resources.

I tried to use the AddMemoryFont method but it doesn't work. I can't find my font in the list and when I look the PrivateFontCollection object, there is one family inside with the name of my font.But all other properties return a compilation error saying:

> the name "name" doesn't exist in the current context

Comment: Word's font list uses only fonts that are installed. Word doesn't know anything about any Font collection used in C#. Word is COM and doesn't natively support things that the .NET Framework can do.

Comment: But when I use AddFontFile to add the font to the PrivateFontCollection, the font is loaded and displayed in the font list. So I guess it could be loaded from resources as well but I can't find how.